# Reposition a board game currently positioned with Tkinter grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building Minesweeper in python with Tkinter and built the adjustable board size with a `for` loop using `grid` to position each value on the window.

Unfortunately I cannot find a way to now reposition the entire grid i.e., I would like to be able to move the game board within the window to place other widgets around it (currently it's auto positioned is the top left corner).

Part of my code is:

```
import tkinter as tk
import configparser

class MainWindow:

    def __init__(self, master):
        """
        """
        self.master = master
        self.config = configparser.SafeConfigParser()
        self.master.geometry("600x600")
        self.master.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.buttons = []

        for row in range(0, 9):
            self.buttons.append([])
            for col in range(0, 9):
                self.button = tk.Button(text=" ", font=("Georgia", "10", "bold"), width=4, height=2,
                                    background="lightsteelblue", relief="raised")

                self.button.bind("<Button-3>")
                self.button.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky=tk.N+tk.W+tk.S+tk.E)
                self.buttons[row].append(self.button)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(background="cornflowerblue")
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This part of the code returns the following:

[image: window with game board]

Which shows the issue I'm having. I would like the ability to move the board within the window (for example, by using `place`) so that I can enlarge the frame and add features around the hopefully centralised board.

Comment: Put your grid of Buttons into a Frame, rather than directly into the window; you can then pack/grid/place that Frame however you want relative to other contents of the window.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for the help Jason!

Answer (score 0):

You should move the buttons into a frame. You can them move the entire group of widgets at once. Even better, create a class specifically for the grid. It would look something like this:

```
class GridFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, rows=10, columns=10, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

        self.buttons = []
        self.grid_rowconfigure([*range(rows)], weight=1, uniform="row")
        self.grid_columnconfigure([*range(columns)], weight=1, uniform="column")

        for row in range(rows):
            self.buttons.append([])
            for col in range(columns):
                button = tk.Button(
                    self,
                    text=" ",
                    font=("Georgia", "10", "bold"),
                    width=4,
                    height=2,
                    background="lightsteelblue",
                    relief="raised",
                )

                button.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky=tk.N + tk.W + tk.S + tk.E)
                self.buttons[row].append(button)
```

You can use this just like you use any other widget. For example:

```
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ """
        self.master = master
        self.config = configparser.SafeConfigParser()
        self.master.geometry("600x600")

        self.board = GridFrame(self.master, rows=10, columns=10, borderwidth=0)
        self.board.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bryan!